# Trailhead Apex Specialist Super Badge test class error

Tags: apex, unit-test, trailhead, superbadges

I am trying to complete the challenge number#5 on the [Advanced Apex Specialist](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_aap) Super badge and I am stuck with an error. I am getting an error stating that the test method doesn't have proper declaration or access modifier but the test method does have all of that. Not sure how to proceed here.

Error Message:
[image]

Test class signature that I have tried with and all have resulted in the same error:

**Option1**

```
@isTest static void OrderUpdate_UnitTest() { ... }
```

**Option2**

```
@isTest private static void OrderUpdate_UnitTest() { ... }
```

**Option3**

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false) private static void OrderUpdate_UnitTest() { ... }
```

**Option4**

```
static testMethod void OrderUpdate_UnitTest() { ... }
```

**Option5**

```
private static testMethod void OrderUpdate_UnitTest() { ... }
```

**EDIT**

TestDataFactory.VerifyQuantityOrdered

```
public static void VerifyQuantityOrdered(Product2 originalProduct, Product2 updatedProduct, Integer qtyOrdered) {
       system.assert(updatedProduct.Quantity_Ordered__c == originalProduct.Quantity_Ordered__c+qtyOrdered);
    }
```

Comment: try using `@IsTest`

Comment: @CasparHarmer, I have tried that but that didn't help out either.

Comment: Open your debugger console and run the verify again. Often you'll see what they want in the debug output.

Comment: I found out the solution to what helped in my scenario. 
I run the Product2Tests and OrderTests individually and checked that have 75% each, rather than a combined 75% with the Run all tests.
Simply duplicated the code of ChartHelper test method to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 things that helped in passing this challenge

1. Created another trailhead playground and moved the code to that org.
2. Added the private modifier to the testSetup method.
3. Added the dummy `OrderExtension_UnitTest()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the Test Class public or the methods themselves public or global?

Not sure how they verify these tests, but assume its a mixture of Metadata API and actually running the tests themselves, and could be the latter not being possible if they are all private. If you have already had tests validated by Trailhead in earlier challenge steps without having to use public though, this answer is probably on the wrong track.

Comment: Yes, I have tried all possible combination of making the method and class public. But the error clearly states to follow 'Best Practices' and the best practices indicate to use private as the modifer and have @isTest instead of testMethod.

Comment: Yeah, agree with you on that. Ideally it should be @isTest private static void.

Out of interest, what happens if you remove whitespace between () and {
so: OrderUpdate_UnitTest(){

Comment: yup, I tried that as well.. But no luck.

Comment: I would recommend logging a support ticket, there is a trailhead support team that are supposed to assist with troubleshooting badges, although in my experience you can wait up to 3 weeks for a response depending on how busy they are.

Other avenues of exploration are:
-create a new trailhead playground and paste the code back in
-turn on logging and inspect in detail whether there is an error payload returned when you check the challenge